# How to remove bullet from details element?

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to remove the little arrow that appears on the left of `<details>` element, but I don't find how to..

Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Thanks

(btw I'm sure that it's makeable easily by editing css styling)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MDN's [`details` element article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#Customizing_the_disclosure_widget) says:

> **The `<summary>` element supports the `list-style` shorthand property** and its longhand properties, such as `list-style-type`, to change the disclosure triangle to whatever you choose (usually with `list-style-image`). For example, we can remove the disclosure widget icon by setting `list-style: none`.
>
> **Chrome doesn't support this yet, however, so we also need to use its non-standard `::-webkit-details-marker` pseudo-element** to customize the appearance in that browser.

Therefore, use `list-style-type` property and `::-webkit-details-marker` pseudo element.

```css
summary {
  list-style-type: none; /* Firefox */
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none; /* Chrome */
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Summary</summary>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Damned, I put this attribute on the details, not on the summary... thanks a lot !